# if-statements with && and || in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

code:

```
// if (image.substring(0,7) != "http://" && image.substring(image.length-4) != ".jpg" || ".png")
if (image.substring(0,7) != "http://" && image.substring(image.length-4) != ".jpg" && image.substring(image.length-4) != ".png")
    {
            // do stuff
    }
```

context: Trying to do an if-statement in JavaScript which uses the && and || operators but it's not working out... Might be due to the fact of how JavaScript returns true-like and false-like values.

**EDIT:**

full code:

```
function validateContent(title, rating, link, image, desc)
{
    var flag = true;

    // add more if-statements
    if (title == "")
    {
        $("#inputTitle").css("background-color", "red");
        flag = false;
    }
    if (rating == 0)
    {
        $("#selectRating").css("background-color", "red");
        flag = false;
    }
    if (link.substring(0,26) != "http://www.imdb.com/title/")
    {
        $("#inputLink").css("background-color", "red");
        flag = false;
    }
    // if (image.substring(0,7) != "http://" && image.substring(image.length-4) != ".jpg" || ".png")
    //if (image.substring(0,7) != "http://" && image.substring(image.length-4) != ".jpg" && image.substring(image.length-4) != ".png")
    //if ((image.substring(0,7) != "http://") && (image.substring(image.length-4) != ".jpg") && (image.substring(image.length-4) != ".png"))
    //if (image.substring(0,7) != "http://" && (image.substring(image.length-4) != ".jpg" || image.substr(image.length-4) !=  ".png"))
    //if (/^http:\/\/.*\.(jpg|png)$/.test(image))
    if ((image.substring(0,7) != "http://") && ((image.substring(image.length-4) == true) != ".jpg") && ((image.substring(image.length-4) == true) != ".png"))
    {
            $("#inputImage").css("background-color", "red");
            flag = false;
    }
    return flag;
}

function addContent()
{
    var title = $("#inputTitle").val();
    var rating = $("#selectRating option:selected").index();
    var link = $("#inputLink").val();
    var image = $("#inputImage").val();
    var desc = $("#textareaDescription").val();

    if (validateContent(title, rating, link, image, desc))
    {
        document.forms.formFilmerPHP.submit();
    }
}

function disableOption(pos)
{
    $("#selectRating option:eq(" + pos + ")").prop("disabled", true);
}

function validateInputs(inputType)
{
    // add more cases
    switch(inputType)
    {
        case "title":
            var title = $("#inputTitle").val();
            if (title != "")
                $("#inputTitle").css("background-color", "white");
            break;
        case "rating":
            var rating = $("#selectRating option:selected").index();
            if (rating != 0)
                $("#selectRating").css("background-color", "white");
            break;
        case "link":
            var link = $("#inputLink").val();
            if (link.substring(0,26) == "http://www.imdb.com/title/")
                $("#inputLink").css("background-color", "white");
            break;
    }
}

function preventDefault()
{
    $("#btnAddContent").click(function(event) {event.preventDefault();});
}

function addEventListeners()    // QUESTION: when to use anonymous functions and when not to when adding eventlisteners in order to safely attach functions without invoking them?
{
    // misc eventlisteners
    $("#selectRating").on("focus", function() {disableOption(0);});

    // real-time polling of invalid input correction
    $("#inputTitle").on("input", function() {validateInputs("title");});                    // QUESTION:    takes some time before this fires, how to make it fire more quickly?
                                                                                                                            // ANSWER:      use the "oninput" event, previously used onkeydown
    $("#selectRating").on("change", function() {validateInputs("rating");});
    $("#inputLink").on("input", function() {validateInputs("link");});

    // main eventlisteners
    $("#btnAddContent").on("click", function() {addContent();});
}

function init()
{
    preventDefault();
    addEventListeners();
}

/* method used to test during development */
function devtest()
{

}

$(document).ready(init);
```

**EDIT:**

```
    var a = image.substring(0,7);
    var b = image.substring(image.length-4);
    alert(a);
    alert(b);
    if(a != "http://" && b != ".jpg" && b != ".png")
    {
            $("#inputImage").css("background-color", "red");    // <-- not being executed
            flag = false;
    }
    return flag;
```

can't get the `$("#inputImage").css("background-color", "red");` statement to execute even though the condition should be evaluated to true.

Comment: At least, assign the value to the image variable so that we can help you understand why this is not working. Also, I don't see any || operator here.

Comment: You should make working the conditions one by one. And try to make compound conditions if they are working already.

Comment: Please explain what the code is supposed to do/which problem you are trying to solve. Also what exactly does not work out? What input do you have and what output do you expect? That it is an `if` statement I can see for myself.

Comment: How 'bout a regex? `if (/^http:\/\/.*\.(jpg|png)$/.test(image)){...}`

Comment: the regex doesn't work, it always evaluates to true.

Comment: Are you taking about the line that is commented out or the one below? I'm just wondering because only the first one actually contains an `||` condition?

Comment: @Ryuji you should post an example/s of such image string and the wanted result vs. *real* result. Further, are you sure that the `image` you're using has the value you assumed ?

Comment: Yes I'm sure because when I input "http://" in the input field it evaluates to true, but if I break it and input "hasdttp://" then it evaluates to false.

Comment: Yeah, must be non-greedy, try `/^http:\/\/.*?\.(jpg|png)$/`. That should do

Comment: What the heck are you doing comparing a string with `true` and then comparing the resulting boolean against another string? `(image.substring(image.length-4) == true) != ".jpg")`

Comment: @elclanrs ok, now it evaluates to false if i input "http://", getting closer, but still no dice if I input "http://asd.jpg"

Comment: I think you need to explain in more detail what you need. That regex will check for images that start with `http://` and end in `.jpg` or `.png`. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: More important than your wall of code is an explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @elclanrs Yeah that's exactly what I'm trying to do. If the string begins with `http://` and ends with `.jpg` or `.png` then the evaluation should return false, thus not executing the following statement: `$("#inputImage").css("background-color", "red");
   flag = false;`

Comment: Then negate the condition `if (! regex.test(string)) {...}`

Comment: `if (!(/^http:\/\/.*?\.(jpg|png)$/))` didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a night of good sleep, here's the proper solution:

```
    var imagebegin = image.substring(0,7);
    var imageend = image.substring(image.length-4);
    if(imagebegin != "http://" || (imageend != ".jpg" && imageend != ".png"))
    {
            $("#inputImage").css("background-color", "red");
            flag = false;
    }
    return flag;
```

The validation will occur only if the beginning of the string is "http://" and the end is either ".jpg" or ".png", if either of these conditions aren't met then the if-statement will evaluate to true and the statements within will be executed (including setting the flag to false).

Answer (score 2):

The below code will be evaluated as true when the first part of the string isn't `http://` and the strings last four characters are neither `.jpg` nor `.png`

```
if (image.substring(0,7) != "http://" && 
    image.substring(image.length-4) != ".jpg" && 
    image.substring(image.length-4) != ".png")
```

Comment: @DaggNabbit - The `||` operator

Comment: @DaggNabbit - I assumed (based on the question title) he meant the javascript that was commented out.

Comment: didn't work, evaluates to true when (image.substring(0,7) != "http://") is satisfied.

Comment: @Ryuji - I think it strange that you ask a question about the `||` operator  when you're not using one in the actual code? I updated my question though.

Comment: @KristerAndersson I did have || originally but it didn't work as expected so I uncommented it, just because it's uncommented doesn't mean that the || operator is irrelevant to the question. I'll check your updated answer. EDIT: still doesn't work.

Comment: @Ryuji - I don't get it? What is it you're trying to achive? The above code will return true as long as the strings first part isn't equal to `http://` and the last 4 characters aren't equal to `.png` or `.jpg`

Comment: @KristerAndersson I think your code might work, problem is that the statements within the if-statements aren't executed for me, I'm debugging it and not getting any wiser.. check my new edit for the question.

Comment: @Ryuji - Make sure your filename is lowercase.

Answer (score -1):

sorry i didnt read your answer proper but i think i gave the right hint anyway

```
if (image.substring(0,7) != "http://" && image.substring(image.length-4) != ".jpg" && (image.substring(image.length-4) != ".png" || image.substring(image.length-4) != 'or'))
```

Comment: didn't work, evaluates to true when (image.substring(0,7) != "http://") is satisfied.